# Load unbuilt gem into irb from that gem's dir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

I'm developing a gem, and I need to load that gem's code into irb for testing purposes without building/publishing the gem and then installing it onto my system the traditional way via `gem install <gem's name>`.

To illustrate:

```
$ pwd
Users/me/development/gem_name/
$ irb
2.2.2 :001 > require 'gem_name'
=> true
```

The problem is that irb isn't loading the gem's code from my working dir because I added a method to the gem in the working dir and it's not available in the version of the gem that irb loaded above.

How can I load the version of the gem that is in the dir that I'm currently working in (i.e. the gem's dir)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `require_relative` to manually load the source code of your gem, for example `require_relative './lib/gem_name/gem_name'` assuming you have a file located at `./lib/gem_name/gem_name.rb` that loads your gem. This guarantees that it is the version you have in your source code.